# How to disarm punch in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What can I do to skyrim to allow my character a chance to disarm any opponent with unarmed fists? Can I do it with an enchanted ring or is there a mod that can incorporate this.

Answer (score 4):

In the base game, you can disarm with the [Disarm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disarm) shout, or by using [Disarming Bash](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block) in the Block tree.  Both of these could conceivably be paired with unarmed combat, but it might not be the experience you're looking for.

The [Unarmed Warfare mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8288/?) adds a relevant Unarmed perk:

> Disarming Blow (requires rank two in Exhilarating Blows, adds chance to disarm)

In the description of this mod, it suggests using the [Way of the Monk mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/15725/?) but that mod doesn't make mention of disarming, and it also appears that development on it has halted.

Comment: Can you enchant a ring with disarm using a console command?

Comment: @linuxfreebird, no, not that I'm aware of.  I don't believe it's one of the [Enchanting Effects](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects) that can be applied to items in the base game.